# libsodium compatibility PHP vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, libsodium, sodium

I have a PHP code that uses the RSA encryption via libsodium (sodium_compat) library.

My script is as below:

```
//https://packagist.org/packages/paragonie/sodium_compat
//composer require paragonie/sodium_compat
require_once "/path/to/sodium_compat/autoload.php";
$privateKey = "HJu4JU0biDAewq0asdfgtDKXlQZZzmVy2chL0x74yhgr";
$publicKey = "874dmkuhiDAewq0asdfgtDKXlQZZzmVy2chL0x74yhgr";
$message = "HJu4JU0biDAewq0hgbvfcdsXlQZZzmVy2chL0x74yhgr";
$encryption_keypair = \Sodium\crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(base64_decode($privateKey), base64_decode($publicKey));
try {
    $decodedMessage = \Sodium\crypto_box_seal_open(base64_decode($message), $encryption_keypair);
    echo $decodedMessage;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The script above shows how I decrypt an encrypted message from an already generated key pair.

I would like to do the same decryption with the same keys in Javascript side to avoid overloading the server, I found this library which is supposed to be the same [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js)

The doc shows how to decrypt as below:

```
let key = sodium.from_hex('724b092810ec86d7e35c9d067702b31ef90bc43a7b598626749914d6a3e033ed');

function encrypt_and_prepend_nonce(message) {
    let nonce = sodium.randombytes_buf(sodium.crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES);
    return nonce.concat(sodium.crypto_secretbox_easy(message, nonce, key));
}

function decrypt_after_extracting_nonce(nonce_and_ciphertext) {
    if (nonce_and_ciphertext.length < sodium.crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES + sodium.crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES) {
        throw "Short message";
    }
    let nonce = nonce_and_ciphertext.slice(0, sodium.crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES),
        ciphertext = nonce_and_ciphertext.slice(sodium.crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES);
    return sodium.crypto_secretbox_open_easy(ciphertext, nonce, key);
}
```

I don't understand how I can make the decryption compatible in PHP and Js, they are refering to a nonce to create with the key in Js but in PHP the same library does not provide that. Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Confusingly, Sodium contains functions called both "box" and "secretbox"; these are not, I believe, interchangeable, and I think you are encrypting with one and decrypting with the other.

Comment: It took me many days to get Libsodium working at all (esp across both JS and PHP). Here is what I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51814273/470749

Answer (score 3):

[This libsodium function reference might help](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use).

You need to use the same group of functions on both sides of the wire.

- `secretbox` -> `secretbox_open`
- `box` -> `box_open`
- `box_seal` -> `box_seal_open`

For `box_seal`, be sure that you're using a public key in JavaScript and the correct secret key in PHP.

If you want shared-key encryption (i.e. same key in both places), use `secretbox`.