# Encrypt on frontend (sodium-plus.js) with public-key from backend (PHP sodium)

Tags: javascript, php, cryptography, libsodium, sodium

I would like to achieve an anonymous public-key encryption in a web browser using `sodium-plus.js` with keys generated in PHP sodium like this:

```
$keyPair = sodium_crypto_box_keypair();

$privateKey = sodium_crypto_box_secretkey($keyPair);
$publicKey = sodium_crypto_box_publickey($keyPair);
```

The keys generated with this method work fine in PHP with the `sodium_crypto_box_seal` and `sodium_crypto_box_seal_open` methods, but however, I am unable to make it work on the frontend. My approach:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/sodium-plus.min.js?v=0.4.2'></script>
<script>
async function getPublicKey() {

    return X25519PublicKey.from(
        '<?php echo sodium_bin2hex($publicKey); ?>', // 6a00b1550ccdeff3886a469b9cd4e5dc9aecd30f5deb3dd3e29fd01f8a32103f
        'hex'
    );

}

async function encryptString(clearText, publicKey) {

    if (!window.sodium) window.sodium = await SodiumPlus.auto();

    let cipherText = await sodium.crypto_box_seal(clearText, publicKey);

    return cipherText.toString('hex');

}

(async function () {

    let clearText = "String that contains secret.";
    let publicKey = await getPublicKey();

    console.log(await encryptString(clearText,publicKey));

})();
</script>
```

This returns **TypeError: Argument 2 must be an instance of X25519PublicKey** in the console.

Notes:

1. A public-key that is derived from `sodium.crypto_box_keypair()` on the frontend works.
2. Tried with `CryptographyKey.from()` instead of `X25519PublicKey.from()` – did not work.
3. The `getPublicKey()` function returns an object wit `buffer: Uint8Array(32) [ … ]`, while the public-key derived from `sodium.crypto_box_keypair()` returns an object with `buffer: Uint8Array(32) [ … ], keyType: "x25519", publicKey: true`.

Concept is based on:

1. https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus/blob/master/docs/SodiumPlus/sealed-boxes.md
2. https://dev.to/paragonie/message-encryption-in-javascript-and-php-cg9
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058638

Comment: Did you figure it out? I copied your code and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Upgrade to version 0.5.0 or later.

The long answer is: Wait until version 0.6.0 is out, and then upgrade to *that* instead, since it also loosens some of the type-pedantic restrictions that you're running into.

Comment: This error doesn't completely go away, even the newer versions. The first time I encrypt and submit, everything works fine, but when I return with a new public key and run the process again, it gives the same error. Only when I re-declare `window.sodium` (basically remove the `if()` statement prefixing it, does the error go away, so something in sodium "remembers" the previous public key. It's an easy fix, but thought I'd give you a heads up in case it's a bug not a feature. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js/ and it works great, encrypts in javascript and decrypts in PHP

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.